# Определение даты в iOS-приложении

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток. Мне нужно сделать вот что: в моем приложении контент отображается в зависимости от дня недели. Я реализовал это так: с помощью NSDate и NSDateFormatter получаю строку с днем недели, потом с помощью оператора условий вывожу контент на экран. Проблема в том, что если поменять язык на устройства, то ничего работать не будет, так как вместо строки "Понедельник" получается строка "Monday". Есть ли способ получить день недели такой строкой, котороя во всем мире будет выглядеть одинаково? Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить номер дня с помощью связки [NSCalendar и NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470-SW7) :

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];

NSInteger day = [weekdayComponents day];

NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

Comment: Хорошо, я попробовал Ваш способ, создал Label который отображает переменную weekday, сегодня воскресенье, сейчас он показывает 1, завтра он покажет 2 и так далее, верно?

Comment: Да, именно так, забыл об этом упомянуть - там используется американская традиция начинать неделю с воскресенья. В принципе, вы можете поиграться и проверить это забив вместо [NSDate date] другую дату (можете получить ее из DatePicker'а или с помощью вот [этой категории][1]). И это не мой способ, он целиком взят из руководства Apple, я просто помню где посмотреть :)

[1]: https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions/blob/master/NSDate%2BUtilities.h

Comment: Ну понедельник будет 2 во все мире или в разных местах по-разному?

Comment: во всем мире

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [NSDataComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/). Есть варианты получения номера дня недели.